# Passing Multiple Parameters to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)
>   [Comma-separated value insertion In SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597607/comma-separated-value-insertion-in-sql-server-2005)

I'm trying to search in my database using where in clause, but my string is in follow format:

```
'233052,57516351,254689'
```

I need to do an consult in my database using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field IN (@list_string)
```

How I do to make this action?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I suggest reading [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html), by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Then [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) are the way to go.

Comment: This question has been asked before; look at [the answer here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1033208/96505

Comment: There 's a few ways to do this and the article mentioned by @Oded will help, but it's messy whichever way you look at it, personally I'd try for an other way to get the same result.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - For a variable list of values, you have to use one of these options. TVPs are probably the best option, when it comes to SQL Server.

Comment: @SimonMartin - for putting links in comments, you have to use the in-line syntax, where you use `[]()`, placing text in the first, and the link in the second.

Comment: @Oded , I know they are out there but i was stuck on sql 2000 as a lowest common denominator for so long (dropped this year :( ) I tend to avoid this scenario by reflex now. and my lcd is now 2005 so I still can't use 'em apparently

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Fair enough. With 2000 you had to go with a delimited string or XML.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), introduced in SQL Server 2008.

These let you pass in a table structure that you can use to query on.

For other options, I suggest reading [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html), by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Itai Goldstein's Split function](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx) for years for this very situation. You could then do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [myTable] 
WHERE [field] IN (
    SELECT [Data]
    FROM [dbo].[Split] (@list_string, ',')
);
```

Comment: Nice, I'll remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try EXEC of sql statement concatenation:

```
declare @sql varchar(200)
set @sql='SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field IN ('+@list_string+')'
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Sql Injection. Build a parameterised query Select * from MyTable Where field = @p1 [Or field = @p2] using the count of values in the list, then  assign the values to the parameters as a safer option.

Comment: @Tony I agree if the list_string is client data, but if the list_string source list is safe and already validated, this will be the fastest execution and best performance query.

Comment: Or query takes longer to parse, because it's longer, doubt it's going to take longer to execute though. The comment was just a heads up for the many many peoples who keep perpetuating sql injection mistake.