# How to pass two list of values to stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

So i am trying for writing a procedure which need to accept the input values in form of two lists as follows:

```
execute ProcedureForInsert 'john,marry,tom' '1,2,3' 40
```

where first parameter is list of Varchar type and second is list of int type and length of both lists are to be same and third parameter is also of int type.

My script is to use these two list values to insert into some table along with third parameter.

How to store and iterate two lists for creation of `Insert Query`  .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comma-separated value insertion In SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597607/comma-separated-value-insertion-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, [look at the **table-valued parameters** feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need a "split string" function that takes a comma separated list and produces a table of the individual strings as output.  There are a lot of these to be found, but look here to start:

[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)